# Node-REDでUndoしたい

Tags: bluemix

Node-REDで操作を間違えたときに元に戻したいのですが方法はありますか。
ヘルプのKeyboard shortcutsのリストにはないようですが。

Answer (score 1):

「Ctrl + Z」でUndoできます。

（「Ctrl + Y」でRedoできると嬉しいのですが、それは実装されていないようです）

Answer (score 1):

ローカルでの開発でよければ、フローを Git で管理する方法が Node-RED ユーザー会で披露されました。
 Flowを自動でgit commitする仕組みを作ってみた話
 http://jaco.udcp.info/flow-git/

Bluemixでは、cloudant の nodered dbに格納されるので、原理的には保存のタイミングで新しいドキュメントを作成することができると思われます。具体的には　couchstorage.js　の saveFlow あたりです。自分で試してなくて申し訳ないです。